# What is the maximum value for x in the command "monerod --db-sync-mode fastest:async:[x]"

Tags: monerod

I've tried:

```
--db-sync-mode fastest:async:100000
```

Is there any maximum/higher value I can use instead of 100000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum value is 2^64-1 (which is, never actually reached in practice).